# How to performe math in between 2 values of dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

Can some one help me on the below:
I have a dictionary that includes two metrics called impression and clicks now to calculate another metric called CTR we need to perform clicks/impression*100.

So will the below statement helps.

To get impressions is :

```
self.campaignDict[campaignId]['Impressions'] = reExp.match(line).group(1)
```

To get clicks is :

```
self.campaignDict[campaignId]['Clicks'] = reExp.match(line).group(1)
```

To Get CTR:

```
`self.campaignDict[campaignId]['CTR'] = self.campaignDict[campaignId][`Clicks]/self.campaignDict[campaignId][Impressions]*100
```

Let me know if i am correct or if anything has to be changed.

Regards,
Sarath

Comment: Looks fine. Is this throwing an error?

Comment: Yes, the below is the error:AttributeError: 'Adnear' object has no attribute 'Clicks'

Comment: so check your `self.campaignDict[campaignId]`  here you are getting error

Comment: If what you've copied above is exact, then I'd suggesting checking closing out quotes and making sure you can access each of these values separately (for instance, the index appears to be 'Impressions' but you're accessing it as Impressions).

Comment: using as below still i get error: self.campaignDict[campaignId]['CTR'] = self.campaignDict[campaignId]['Clicks']/self.campaignDict[campaignId]['Impressions']*100
KeyError: 'Clicks'

Comment: Check what does this returns ? print self.campaignDict[campaignId]['Clicks']. If this returns 'None' means there is missing key for 'Clicks'